# Redmine slow view rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine

I need to be able to identify why is view rendering slow.

On first server, it renders /settings like this:

```
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 79.6ms | ActiveRecord: 19.8ms)
```

But on another server:

```
Completed 200 OK in 8670ms (Views: 8559.7ms | ActiveRecord: 83.7ms)
```

Here is complete debug log:

```
Started GET "/settings" for 24.135.248.215 at 2017-05-14 12:03:08 +0200
Processing by SettingsController#index as HTML
  SQL (6.9ms)  UPDATE `tokens` SET `tokens`.`updated_on` = '2017-05-14 12:03:08' WHERE `tokens`.`user_id` = 1 AND `tokens`.`value` = 'a84ab330b53c2becd16dee761ef3048bdb664834' AND `tokens`.`action` = 'session'
   (0.6ms)  SELECT MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) FROM `settings`
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`status` = 1 AND `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'commit_update_keywords'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'welcome_text'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'text_formatting'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'per_page_options'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'search_results_per_page'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'activity_days_default'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'host_name'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'protocol'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'cache_formatted_text'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'wiki_compression'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'feeds_limit'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_general.html.erb (419.7ms)
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'force_default_language_for_anonymous'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'start_of_week'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  UserPreference Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `user_preferences`.* FROM `user_preferences` WHERE `user_preferences`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'date_format'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (3.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'time_format'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'user_format'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'thumbnails_enabled'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'thumbnails_size'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'new_item_menu_tab'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_display.html.erb (868.7ms)
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'login_required'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'autologin'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'self_registration'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'unsubscribe'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'password_min_length'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'password_max_age'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'lost_password'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'max_additional_emails'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'openid'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'default_users_hide_mail'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_authentication.html.erb (1338.9ms)
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'rest_api_enabled'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'jsonp_enabled'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_api.html.erb (82.0ms)
  Setting Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'default_projects_public'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'default_projects_modules'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Tracker Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `trackers`.* FROM `trackers`  ORDER BY `trackers`.`position` ASC
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'default_projects_tracker_ids'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'sequential_project_identifiers'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`builtin` = 0  ORDER BY `roles`.`position` ASC
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'new_project_user_role_id'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_projects.html.erb (546.8ms)
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'cross_project_issue_relations'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'link_copied_issue'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'cross_project_subtasks'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'issue_group_assignment'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'default_issue_start_date_to_creation_date'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'display_subprojects_issues'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'issue_done_ratio'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'non_working_week_days'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'issues_export_limit'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'gantt_items_limit'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'parent_issue_dates'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'parent_issue_priority'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'parent_issue_done_ratio'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'issue_list_default_columns'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  IssueCustomField Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `custom_fields`.* FROM `custom_fields` WHERE `custom_fields`.`type` IN ('IssueCustomField')
  Tracker Load (2.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `trackers`.* FROM `trackers` INNER JOIN `projects_trackers` ON `projects_trackers`.`tracker_id` = `trackers`.`id` INNER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `projects_trackers`.`project_id` WHERE (projects.status <> 9 AND projects.id IN (SELECT em.project_id FROM enabled_modules em WHERE em.name='issue_tracking'))  ORDER BY `trackers`.`position` ASC
  Rendered queries/_columns.html.erb (669.8ms)
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'issue_list_default_totals'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `custom_fields`.* FROM `custom_fields` WHERE `custom_fields`.`type` IN ('IssueCustomField')
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `trackers`.* FROM `trackers` INNER JOIN `projects_trackers` ON `projects_trackers`.`tracker_id` = `trackers`.`id` INNER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `projects_trackers`.`project_id` WHERE (projects.status <> 9 AND projects.id IN (SELECT em.project_id FROM enabled_modules em WHERE em.name='issue_tracking'))  ORDER BY `trackers`.`position` ASC
  Rendered settings/_issues.html.erb (1922.1ms)
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'attachment_max_size'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'attachment_extensions_allowed'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'attachment_extensions_denied'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'file_max_size_displayed'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'diff_max_lines_displayed'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'repositories_encodings'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_attachments.html.erb (369.8ms)
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'mail_from'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'bcc_recipients'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'plain_text_mail'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'default_notification_option'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'notified_events'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'emails_header'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'emails_footer'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_notifications.html.erb (739.1ms)
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'mail_handler_body_delimiters'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'mail_handler_excluded_filenames'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'mail_handler_api_enabled'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'mail_handler_api_key'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/_mail_handler.html.erb (252.3ms)
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'enabled_scm'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'autofetch_changesets'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'sys_api_enabled'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'sys_api_key'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'repository_log_display_limit'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'commit_ref_keywords'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'commit_cross_project_ref'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'commit_logtime_enabled'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  TimeEntryActivity Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `enumerations`.* FROM `enumerations` WHERE `enumerations`.`type` IN ('TimeEntryActivity') AND `enumerations`.`project_id` IS NULL AND `enumerations`.`active` = 1  ORDER BY `enumerations`.`position` ASC
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'commit_logtime_activity_id'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `trackers`.* FROM `trackers`  ORDER BY `trackers`.`position` ASC
  IssueStatus Load (3.8ms)  SELECT `issue_statuses`.* FROM `issue_statuses`  ORDER BY `issue_statuses`.`position` ASC
  Rendered settings/_repositories.html.erb (775.2ms)
  Rendered common/_tabs.html.erb (7662.4ms)
  Rendered settings/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin (7755.6ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (375.6ms)
  SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT `members`.`id` AS t0_r0, `members`.`user_id` AS t0_r1, `members`.`project_id` AS t0_r2, `members`.`created_on` AS t0_r3, `members`.`mail_notification` AS t0_r4, `members`.`dmsf_mail_notification` AS t0_r5, `members`.`title_format` AS t0_r6, `projects`.`id` AS t1_r0, `projects`.`name` AS t1_r1, `projects`.`description` AS t1_r2, `projects`.`homepage` AS t1_r3, `projects`.`is_public` AS t1_r4, `projects`.`parent_id` AS t1_r5, `projects`.`created_on` AS t1_r6, `projects`.`updated_on` AS t1_r7, `projects`.`identifier` AS t1_r8, `projects`.`status` AS t1_r9, `projects`.`lft` AS t1_r10, `projects`.`rgt` AS t1_r11, `projects`.`inherit_members` AS t1_r12, `projects`.`default_version_id` AS t1_r13, `projects`.`dmsf_description` AS t1_r14, `projects`.`dmsf_notification` AS t1_r15 FROM `members` INNER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `members`.`project_id` WHERE `members`.`user_id` = 1 AND (projects.status<>9)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_tweaks/app/views/application/_global_html_header.erb (4.4ms)
  Attachment Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `attachments`.* FROM `attachments` WHERE `attachments`.`container_id` = 1 AND `attachments`.`container_type` = 'Principal' AND `attachments`.`description` = 'avatar'  ORDER BY attachments.created_on ASC, attachments.id ASC LIMIT 1
  EmailAddress Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `email_addresses`.* FROM `email_addresses` WHERE `email_addresses`.`user_id` = 1 AND `email_addresses`.`is_default` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Project Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `projects`.`id`, `projects`.`name`, `projects`.`identifier`, `projects`.`lft`, `projects`.`rgt` FROM `projects` INNER JOIN `members` ON `projects`.`id` = `members`.`project_id` WHERE `members`.`user_id` = 1 AND (projects.status<>9) AND `projects`.`status` = 1
  Rendered plugins/redmine_tweaks/app/views/application/_global_content.erb (30.5ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_tweaks/app/views/application/_global_footer.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (461.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8670ms (Views: 8559.7ms | ActiveRecord: 83.7ms)
```

App info:

```
Ruby version                   2.3.3-p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version                  4.2.7.1
```

Comment: Is both are same mode( ex: production) and same code?

Comment: *two almost same Redmine installations*, okay?! But how do the installations differ? Database? Versions? Different views?

Comment: Yes, same. Is there a way to see what is causing render slowdowns?

Comment: There was something mentioned in some gem that it's updated and might cause problems with app.

Comment: I'm pretty confident some gem is causing it

Answer (score 2):

Hm, so now:

```
Started GET "/settings" for 24.135.248.215 at 2017-05-15 21:07:04 +0200
Processing by SettingsController#index as HTML
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered settings/_general.html.erb (33.4ms)
  Rendered settings/_display.html.erb (44.1ms)
  Rendered settings/_authentication.html.erb (36.3ms)
  Rendered settings/_api.html.erb (6.2ms)
  Rendered settings/_projects.html.erb (69.4ms)
  Rendered queries/_columns.html.erb (56.7ms)
  Rendered settings/_issues.html.erb (121.0ms)
  Rendered settings/_attachments.html.erb (13.4ms)
  Rendered settings/_notifications.html.erb (19.1ms)
  Rendered settings/_mail_handler.html.erb (8.8ms)
  Rendered settings/_repositories.html.erb (100.0ms)
  Rendered common/_tabs.html.erb (497.5ms)
  Rendered settings/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin (502.0ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_tweaks/app/views/application/_global_html_header.erb (8.4ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_tweaks/app/views/application/_global_content.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_tweaks/app/views/application/_global_footer.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (39.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 581ms (Views: 483.5ms | ActiveRecord: 83.9ms)
```

What I did was:

```
 bundle clean --force
 rvm gemset empty
 rm -rf .bundle
 gem install bundler
 bundle install --without development test
```

I'm not sure what exactly resolved the issue, is it gems, or fact that **now I installed without development and test.**